# How to component test web api using in memory hosting framework while web api still runs on iis?

Tags: testing, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm trying to create component testing project to test a Web API service and I would like to use in memory hosting solution such as OWIN, I would like to know is it possible and also is it possible that the Web API project would run with IIS and only the testing project will run in memory?

Is there any recommended in memory hosting framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Owin to self host your api so you can perform test against a running version of your api. However, you should be able to test your controllers logic using unit tests without requiring your api's to be actually hosted.

Still, there might be valid reason to host them in a unit test so here we go:

Self hosting in a console application is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api). If it can run in a console application it can run in a unit test project as well. An example could be (pseudo code):

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
using Owin
using System.Web.Http
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors
using System.Web.Http.Dispatcher
using System.Threading.Tasks

string service = "http://localhost:54321";

[TestMethod]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    using (var webApp = WebApp.Start(service, BuildConfiguration))
    {
        var requestUrl = string.Format($"{service}/api/Foo/Bar");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
        Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);    
    }
}

public void BuildConfiguration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var HttpConfiguration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();

    HttpConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new AssembliesResolver());

    HttpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
                $"api/{{controller}}/{{action}}/{{id}}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });


    appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(HttpConfiguration);

    HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized();
}

[RoutePrefix("api/Foo")]
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Bar")]
    public string GetBar()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

public class AssembliesResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    private List<Assembly> assemblies;

    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        assemblies = new List<Assembly> { GetType().Assembly };

        return assemblies;
    }
}
```

Now, your controllers to test probably live in another assembly than in the test assembly. You might have to use an assemblies resolver for the unit test project to be able to discover your api's. You can write your own AssembliesResolver for that as shown in my answer.

Be aware though. Depending on your setup you have to make sure your test environment matches the real world scenario. There might be subtle differences between IIS and self hosted web api's when it comes to the different parameters required to set up the in memory hosting environment

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @ReaB., if this answer works for you, please [mark it so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @BrockAdams I did, thanks

Comment: @ReaB., the record shows you didn't.  You need to tick the green checkmark.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 .